# force:refreshView doesn't refresh record related lists as community user

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, quickaction, refresh

I have a custom lightning component that, after some operations, do a `$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire()` but it's refreshing everything except the current record related lists.

I've read this is some kind of long ago reported bug but, is there anyway to achieve this without using `window.location.reload()`?

Comment: We would need more details like how your community is setup and what the related list is. For internal users, `force:refreshView` does refreshes the whole page including the components. If you have this as a custom component, you may need to have a event listener for refresh: `<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.handleRefresh}"/>`